# How to add files to the root of a RAR archive in Linux

Tags: linux, rar

I have an Ubuntu Server and use `rar` with the `exec()` function. When I want to create a RAR archive from my files, this program uses their path in my RAR archive.

For example, if my file is in `/home/user/video/some.flv` and my php program is in `/home/user`, it will added as `video/some.flv` — however I want the file path to be `some.flv`.

I also don't want to copy my file to where my php program is, so I need a way to change the path. I used this:

```
rar rn archive.rar video/some.flv some.flv
```

… but when I try to extract it, it tells me the file label is "wrong or damaged". What can I do? I have many big files in different paths and want all of them to be in the root path of my RAR archive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding the `-ep` (exclude path) switch to rar.  So when you add new files, it would be something like:

```
rar a -ep archive.rar video/some.flv
```

but rar should add it to the archive as simply `some.flv`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the command you execute (from your php app) is something like

```
rar a archive.rar video/some.flv
```

According to `rar --help`,

> ep --- Exclude path from names

Adding the `-ep` like so

```
rar a -ep archive.rar video/some.flv
```

causes the paths to be omitted in the rar, and all the files you have added will show up in the folder they are extracted to and not in a subfolder.

I couldn't figure out how to do the same as `tar`'s `-C`, but I hope this does what you needed.